# AJAX autocomplete textbox in Java web technology (JSP and servlets)

Tags: java, html, ajax, jsp, servlets

Please I need your assistance on how to make HTML input text element work like "Google's AJAX search engine" input text element with Java web technology (JSP, servlets and AJAX). Data on the drop-down list will be from a database table, e.g MySQL or Microsoft SQL databases respectively.

I studied the NetBeans tutorial on this, but selecting a value from the drop-down list to appear in the HTML input text element isn't possible with that tutorial. Here's the [link](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/ajax-quickstart.html).

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked this [link](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)? All what you need to do is get your db values as a list and store it in that variable. Hope you can do that..

Comment: from google i was able to turn up a few tutorials rather quickly - here's a "live search example" http://blog.ninetofive.me/blog/build-a-live-search-with-ajax-php-and-mysql/

Comment: @Vinoth Kristnan...ur idea is simple and straight forward. Lets say I retrieve the db values into an array in a servlet, how do i use the array in javascript. Thanks.

Comment: @Joe. Thanks. I am trying to study the php code in that link to see if I can implement the same concept with jsp and java servlet.

Answer (score 3):

@user2870719 You can try like following, In your jsp page send a ajax request to a servlet/jsp and fill the response data in a javascript variable. So you can get the jQuery autocomplete textbox as i mentioned above.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showData(value){ 
$.ajax({
    url : "ur_servlet?name="+value,
    type : "POST",
    async : false,
    success : function(data) {
//Do something with the data here
    }
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="employee">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" onkeyup="showData(this.value);"><br>


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And in servlet,

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String buffer="";  
try{
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root", "root");
   Statement st=con.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from data where name like '"+name+"%'");
    while(rs.next())
    {
    buffer=buffer+"'"+rs.getString("name")+"',";
    }
response.getWriter().println(buffer);
}
 catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Finally send the response to jsp page. Let me know if this helps..

Comment: May be this [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-create-autocomplete-feature-with-java-jsp-jquery/) also useful for you.

Comment: As a side note: it is pointless to call `toString()` in `request.getParameter("name").toString()`, because the [ServletRequest#getParameter(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)) already **returns String**.

Comment: @Vinoth Kristnan....thanks for the link...but I intend to do a lot ajax dropdownlist which means I will have so many jsp pages...which could cause code maintenance issues...thanks for the link

Comment: @VinothKrishnan still studying the code you pasted here though...thanks

Comment: @user2870719 Glad you got some idea from the post. This is one kind of implementation. You need to find a optimal way to fix your issue.

Comment: What do i have to do to show the text from jsp in the input field? Thanks

Comment: I used "onkeypress="showDataC(this.value)"" that call a javascript that query on a Servlet. I used JQUERY autocmplete. This is the JS function showDataC(value) {
  var x=null;
  $.ajax({
   url : "categoriaServlet?action=autoC&name=" + value,
   type : "POST",
   async : false,
   success : function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    x = data;
    
   }
  });
  $("#name").autocomplete({ source: x
  });
 };

Comment: You can use `$("#your_text_box_id").val(data);` in your ajax response to display the output in textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete- Jquery Ajax Json Example in Java(using Servlet)

Here am using devbridge jquery api to achieve the autocomplete functionality.

Requirements:
  
 Eclipse
 
 Mysql (or you can use any other database ,but in lib folder you must add appropriate driver
   for  that database)

To get country list
For Mysql
https://github.com/bharathirasa/demo/blob/master/mysql-country-list-codes.sql

For Oracle
https://github.com/bharathirasa/demo/blob/master/oracle-country-list.sql

**HTML Code** 
`<input type="text" name="country" id="autocomplete"
 class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Country name" />`

**Jquery Code**

```
     $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
                              //lookup: countries,
                              serviceUrl:'Auto', //tell the script where to send requests
                               width: 450, //set width
//callback just to show it's working
                              onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                              $('#selection').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
                              },
                              showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
                              noSuggestionNotice: 'Sorry, no matching results',
               });
```

**Servlet Code**

```
                                     String q=request.getParameter("query");
                                     ArrayList<Country> o=CountryDao.getCountryName(q);
                                     Gson gson = new Gson();
                                     // convert java object to JSON format,
                                     // and returned as JSON formatted string
                                     String json = gson.toJson(o);
                                     //System.out.println(json);
                                     response.getWriter().write("{\"suggestions\":"+json+"}");
```

Here the method is not mentioned so all the data will be passed as GET method. If you want to pass the data through post mention in Jquery like type:’POST’.


hi actually i created an autocomplete in java using devbridge jquery api

follow the link to get more info

http://pdfboxtutorial.blogspot.com/2015/03/autocomplete-jquery-ajax-json-example.html

Comment: as per your comment i posted the code here @S.L.Barth